# How do I approach a "stuck" game of minesweeper?

Tags: strategy, minesweeper

I've played many a-game of minesweeper, and I frequently reach positions in which there is no logical, deterministic way to come to a conclusion about how I should solve the puzzle.

How should I best approach solving these puzzles to guarantee the highest statistical victory?

> Meta-context: this question is an offshoot of [this original question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/357/how-do-i-win-minesweeper-every-time/358), which feedback indicated was [somewhat too broad](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159/how-broad-is-too-broad-for-how-do-i-solve-this-puzzle-questions/).

Comment: Don't click the top left corner. Apparently if your first click is a mine, then that is where it is relocated to and your first click is "safe". Aside from that, being lucky is probably your best bet.

Comment: Just for your information: Simon Tatham's Portable Puzzle Collection features an  implementation of Minesweeper that is guaranteed to be dead-end-free. As its name suggests, it is available for many platforms. http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/

Comment: with great caution :)

Comment: There's a smiley face button in the top center of the game. Press that.

Answer (score 7):

In general, when looking at these situations, you want to click on the squares that are the *least* likely to contain mines. This will invariably give you more information about your current situation.

Here's an example of a game that can't be beaten without strict testing, which I will use to demonstrate what I mean.

> [image]

There are two mines remaining. I apologize, but the 3 underneath the square labeled 2 actually has two adjacent flags, and needs one more flag; one of them was cut off in the screenshot.

Because there is a 1 next to 1 and 2, I know that one of these must be a mine. If 1 is a mine, then 2 is not, which means one of 4, 5, 6 is a mine, and 3 is not. This gives three cases when 1 is a mine.

If 1 is not a mine, then 2 is a mine. If 2 is a mine, then none of 4, 5, 6 is a mine, which means 3 must be a mine. This has only one case.

Therefore, the number of cases where 1 is a mine is 3/4; the number of cases where it is not is 1/4. We can proceed assuming that 1 is a mine - and as it happens to turn out, it is.

---

> [image]

Here's another example of a possible setup. The method I use in these cases effectively can be extended across the entire board (which makes it a bit more accurate), but I only execute it a few levels in my head. Here's how my thought process works:

We can see that if 5 is a mine, then 4 can't be, which means 3 is. At this point, either 1 or 2 could be a mine, which gives two cases.

If 5 isn't a mine, then 4 must be a mine, which means 3 isn't, which means both 1 and 2 are - which gives one case.

Therefore, the situation in which 5 is a mine covers 2/3 of the cases, and the situations in which 5 isn't covers 1/3. Therefore, we proceed on the assumption that 5 is a mine.

Of course, there are more than three cases for the entire grid - this is only a rough estimate. I could go into further detail about what the squares above 1 and 2 could be, as well as the surrounding squares, but I won't here. It all depends on how long you want to take and how accurate you want to be.

Comment: Fair criticisms. I'll update the answer later tonight.

Comment: ", said Emrakul a week ago ;-)

Comment: @Jan .....whoooops. Totally slipped through the cracks there. Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: The formatting on this answer looks weird. The LaTex is not converting for me... ?

Comment: @Emrakul can i edit it to make the LaTex work or is that in the answer what you intended...?

Comment: @manshu Feel free to fix it if you want! Though I'll probably get to it later today. Should be an easy find and replace. (It's a leftover artifact from when we changed the LaTeX start symbol from `\$` to `$` a loooong time ago.)

Comment: Could someone that understands this answer post correct screenshots?